# How to add files by drag and drop or file dialog using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to insert files from my computer by file dialog and also through drag and drop.

To do so i have the input type file for file dialog insertion and drag and drop component for dragging and dropping files.

Below is my code,

```
Class AddfilesDiv extends react.Purecomponent {
    state = {
        files: [],
    }
    on_files_added = e => {
        let files;
        if (e.type==="drop") {
            files = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.dataTransfer.files);
        } else {
            files = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.target.files);
        }
            this.setState({files});
    }
    return (
        <DragAndDrop handle_drop={this.on_files_added}>
            <div className="files_container_wrapper">
                <div className="files_container">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handle_file_addition}>
                        <div className="file_names">
                            <label>
                                <div className="add_files_btn">
                                    <Svgplus/>
                                </div>
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    onChange={this.on_files_added}
                                    style={{ display: 'none' }}
                                    multiple 
                                />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </DragAndDrop>);
    }

export class DragAndDrop extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dragging: false,
        };
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         document.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handle_drag_in);
         document.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handle_drag_out);
         document.addEventListener('dragover', this.handle_drag);
         document.addEventListener('drop', this.handle_drop);
     }

     handle_drop = (e) => {
         this.props.handle_drop(e);
     }
     render () {
         return (
             //some code
         );
     }
 }
```

Now the on_files_added method sets the files state and displays them one by one in the div.

the above code lists multiple files when selecting files at once and adding...but when i add one file it shows up in the div and when i again open file dialog and select another file it replaces previous selected file. this is the same with drag and drop.

What i want?

it should list all files when i multiselect files and add also when i select one file from file dialog it should show up in the files div and selecting another file again should showup the other file aswell instead of replacing...

how can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: If you don't have to write it by yourself, you can use an exiting library, such as: https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/examples

Comment: Legit. Just notice that this is pretty big work (not just fix a line or something) because it requires to implement sort of queue for uploading the files. I'm not sure you will get such a help here :| My suggestion, try to implement it and if you get stuck, then comeback and ask..